# Htaccess file redirects wrong ip's

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect spam ip's from my website to a different website.

For some reason the following code in my .htaccess file redirects me (my ip) to the www.underconstruction.com despite my ip not being included. My ip has the following format 5.64...

Please, could you help me improve the following code so that it redirects only the listed ip's / ip ranges   to www.underconstruction.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^88\.208\.201\.208 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^209\.190 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^209\.51 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^5\.101 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^62\.210 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^62\.212
RewriteRule ^/* http://www.underconstruction.com/ [L]
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log?  
Try to use REMOTE_HOST instead of REMOTE_ADDR

Comment: When it comes to the error log, do you mean the log report from my hosting provider? If yes, then I should be able to have this information later today.

I've also have just replaced REMOTE_ADDR with REMOTE_HOST as per your suggestion, and it seems that now I can access the site. So this might be the right solution to my problem. Thank you Johni.

Comment: @Johni Could you put that up as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using the following code in the .htaccess file. The REMOTE_HOST parameter has been used instead of the REMOTE_ADDR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^88\.208\.201\.208 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^209\.190 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^209\.51 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^5\.101 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^62\.210 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^62\.212
RewriteRule ^/* http://www.underconstruction.com/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your error log? Try to use REMOTE_HOST instead of REMOTE_ADDR